# Vector multiplication. Matrix form

Tags: vectors

If I want to multiply two vectors by means of matrices, one of them must be transposed in order to perform multiplication.
Does it matter which vector should be transposed or can I choose randomly (that sounds incorrect) which vector to be transposed?

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: There's a big difference between $u^tv$ and $uv^t$. Try it for an example.

Comment: @GerryMyerson (Sorry for this off-topic comment, but there is a new user at Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange with the same name as yours.  FYI.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to "multiply vectors".  Which multiplication? There are three different kinds of multiplications used with vectors- the "dot product" (also called "inner product"), "cross product" and "scalar product".  Since you say "vectors", plural, and the scalar product involves one vector and one scalar, I will drop the scalar product.  The cross product is "anti-commutative", uxv= -vxu so certainly changing the order will change that.  For the dot product we can do either $\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p \\ q \\ r\end{pmatrix}= ap+ bq+ cr$ or $\begin{pmatrix}p & q & r\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}= pa+ qb+ rc$, the same thing!

But $\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p & q & r\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}ap & aq & ar \\ bp & bq & br \\ cp & cq & cr \end{pmatrix}$ is completely different!

Comment: I was talking about the dot product.
Thank you for clarification in this regard.